# Horizontal lines between level-one nodes (L&F independent)

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I would like to create horizontal line separators between level-one nodes in jtree. All of them equal in size. There is a great solution [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/Producehorizontallinesbetweenlevelonenodes.htm), however It works only on Metal L&F (I don't use it in my application). How can I create the same effect with just a jtree and its renderer? What is the best way to do it?

I tried approach with setting node border but it's not it.

Comment: How ??? --- I tried approach with setting node border but it's not it.

Comment: answer to your queston this is only Metal property

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do this:

1. Extend class MetalTreeUI
2. Modify it to meet your requirements (especially method "paintHorizontalSeparators").
3. Set your class as the new tree UI.